# Array in function (Массив и функция)

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как выполнить данную задачу???

Comment: `const fillArray = (n) => Array.from({ length: n / 2 }, (_, i) => (i + 1) * 2);`

Comment: ```function fillArray(n) {let s=''; for (let i=2;i<=n;i+=2){s+=i+','} return JSON.parse(`[${s.substr(0,s.length-1)}]`)}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с циклом:

```
function fillArray(n) {
  let res = []
  for (let i = 2; i <= n; i += 2) {
    res.push(i)
  }
  return res
}
```

Comment: `for (let i = 2; i < n; i += 2) { res.push(i); }`

Comment: Исправил лишние проверки и итерации, спасибо